# find out package dependencies before installation?

Tags: python, dependency-management

is there a way one can find out package dependencies before installation?

For example say I wanted to install `open3D` I create a virtual environment -> activate it -> and start installing packages. Well sometimes when I do this I get errors like `package conflicts` about numpy, matplotlib versions, and so on.

Is there a good practice for being able to find out which library versions these packages depend on prior to installing a package?

Comment: I suppose that using `pip` should *install* all the **libraries** you need to use open3D, the documentation also indicates that you should check, I recommend that the version you install is the latest, both `Python 3.9` and [open3D](https://storage.googleapis.com/open3d-releases-master/python-wheels/open3d-0.15.1-cp39-cp39-linux_x86_64.whl)

Comment: so I am speaking in more of a general purpose.